# Place default profile image based on gender in django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-models, savechanges

I need help on selecting a default profile picture depending on the gender of the user..
I have three default images in my media folder that i want to use as defaults, namely "00.png, 01.png, and 02.png".

models.py

```py
GenderChoice = (
    ('others', 'Others'),
    ('male', 'Male'),
    ('female' :'Female')
) 

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    gender = models.CharField(choice=GenderChoice)
    pro_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to ="", default ="00.png")
```

what I want is if a user selects gender="others" then 00.png should be saved as default and if they select male the 01.png should be selected as default..

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This becomes much easier if you think of it as "I want to **show** a different default based on gender if the user does not have an image uploaded":

```py
from django.templatetags.static import static
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    gender = models.CharField(choice=GenderChoice)
    pro_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to ="", null=True)
    default_pic_mapping = { 'others': '00.png', 'male': '01.png', 'female': '02.png'}

    def get_profile_pic_url(self):
        if not self.pro_pic:
            return static('img/{}'.format(self.default_pic_mapping[self.gender]))
        return self.pro_pic.url
```